# Limits Properties of exponential function

Tags: real-analysis

Rudin in his PMA defines: $$E(x)=\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{z^n}{n!} \quad (z\in \mathbb{C}) \qquad (1)$$
He write that "these limits follows directly from (1)"

1) $E(x)\to +\infty$ as $x\to +\infty$.

2) $\dfrac{E(h)-1}{h}\to 1$ as $h\to 0$.

I can't understand how the directly follows from (1). Can anyone explain these limits, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

For real-values of $x$ and $x\ge0$, we have

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}\ge 1+x$$

In addition, we have

$$\frac{E(h)-1}{h}=1+\frac12h+O(h^2)$$

Alternatively, we have for $h<1$

$$1+h \le E(h)\le \frac{1}{1-h}$$

since $\frac{1}{1-h}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}h^n$.  Therefore,

$$1\le \frac{E(h)-1}{h}\le \frac{h}{1-h}$$

Then, use the Squeeze Theorem.

Comment: The first inequality is good but Rudin considers $x\to +\infty$? But you wrote $x\ge 0$. Can you extend your answer in detail please?

Comment: By the way, I don't know notion $O(h^2)$. Rudin never introduced this notion

Comment: @RaheemNajib It is valid for all $x\ge 0$.  So, what is the limit of $1+x$ as $x\to \infty$?

Comment: It's limit $+\infty$.

Comment: @RaheemNajib "Big O" notation is defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Comment: So, if $1+x\to \infty$ and $1+x$ is smaller than $E(x)$, what can one deduce about the limit of $E(x)$?

Comment: May be you meant $1+x$ is less than $E(x)$?

Comment: Yes.  That is what I wrote in the HINT.

Comment: Am I right that second question can be proved without using big O-notation?

Comment: There are many ways to skin a math problem.  What approach do you have in mind?

Comment: I meant that I'm interested in proof without using O-notation.

Comment: I just provided another approach.

Comment: Excellent! Your $h<1$ right? But what about lower bound?

Comment: How you got that $E(h)>1+h$?

Comment: @RaheemNajib All the terms of the series are positive when $h>0$.  The first two terms are $1+h$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for big help, dear Dr. MV!

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.

Comment: What did you think about below proof of RFZ?

Comment: You think that it's false? Why? He reaaly showed that limit is equal to zero.

Comment: But his proof is not false. Right?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can prove that $\lim \limits_{h\to 0}\frac{E(h)-1}{h}=1$ directly from definition of limit.

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given then taking $\delta=\min \{\epsilon,1\}$ for any $h\in \mathbb{R}$ with $|h|<\delta$ we have: $$\left|\frac{E(h)-1}{h}-1\right|=\left|\frac{h}{2!}+\frac{h^2}{3!}+\cdots+\frac{h^n}{(n+1)!}+\cdots\right|\le$$$$\le \dfrac{|h|}{2^1}+\dfrac{|h|^2}{2^2}+\dots +\dfrac{|h|^n}{2^n}+\cdots \leqslant \epsilon.$$